# How can I troubleshoot a localhost error?

Tags: java, tomcat, github, intellij-idea

[image: screenshot of error]I'm working on a project pulled from GitHub in IntellijIdea. I am able to build my project and have a database running, but when I try to run it using Tomcat, I get an error in Chrome saying that there is no webpage attached to local port 8080.

I've tried building and rebuilding artifacts, reconfigured Tomcat using different ports, and tried previewing the project through index.jsp, but I continue to get this error.

I'm expecting to see a map and webpage (as my teammates can), but am having no luck. Does anyone have thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you provide some more information, like which github projekt?

Comment: Did you check and verify the tomcat logs to see the server started with no issues?

Comment: See https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-run-debug-web-application-on-tomcat/. Make sure the deployment context was specified correctly.

Comment: I'm getting no errors/warnings in the tomcat log, and went through the instructions in the mkyong link. Is there somewhere to look next?